# django model: check relation before saving the object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-validation

I have django model consists of two class `annualReport` and `annualReportAttachment`

The relation between the two models is `oneToMany`. In the admin form I need to validation that the user has uploaded at least one file so I use the following clean method in the `annualReport` class

```
def clean(self):
    attachments = annualReportAttachment.objects.filter(annualReport=self)
    if len(attachments) == 0:
        raise ValidationError("You should upload at least one file")
```

The problem is that the attached files is not saved yet so the `attachments` variable is empty and the form always raise that error.

How could I check that the user has uploaded at least one file?

Comment: if len(attachments) > 0:

Comment: Is annualReportAttachment represented as an inline model in your admin class for annualReport?

Comment: @Brandon yes it is an inline model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that at least one form in your inline model gets saved. To do this, I would recommend leveraging the RequireOneFormSet class from https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/WadOfStuffDjangoForms

Comment: is there any other solution of workaround instead of `RequireOneFormSet` ?

Comment: You can always write your own, but you'll end up writing the same logic as presented in the RequireOneFormSet class. I have used that class on numerous projects where at least one inline model is required, and it works great.

Comment: What about the RequireOneFormSet class won't suit your needs?

Comment: nop it does. I just believe there is a much simpler solution to check that the related objects are there before saving.

Comment: That's the beauty of OpenSource. If you can come up with something simpler, I'd love to see the solution you arrive at.